# Change StatusBar in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

how to change status bar from one page to another for example (`traslucent`) and that the second component loads after applying the property.

What happens now is that it charges and it is seen when it changes.

My code

```
componentWillMount () {
StatusBar.setTraslucent (true);
)
```

Comment: Could you please better explain the problem? I'm not sure if I'm understanding it correctly

Comment: when I navigate from one component to another, I see the effect of adding and removing traslucent. I would like you not to notice that you enter a component and see yourself with the traslucent

Comment: Try setting it before you call the navigate method

Comment: I already tried if
enter the second component and you see the effect lagging

Comment: Btw is this on android or ios